# VB.Net TextBox Equation Reader

Tags: vb.net, textbox, equation, integral

I try to make a program to calculate integrals. I want to read the equation from a textbox and i don't know how to store it. For example i write in the textbox : 3x^2+2x+1. How can i make some arrays to store every member of that equation and to solve it ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please post the code that you have so far so it's easier for people to help you

Comment: I dont have the code.I just want some ideas.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: What is the problem? "Not all questions benefit from including code"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should include code if you want people to help you. I have a suggestion but it really all depends. Are you only wanting to put the numbers in an array or all characters and symbols? Or are you wanting to put the entire equation as one entry in the array? I am not sure an array would be the best route to go for this sort of thing. But whatever.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim EqArray() As string

Public Sub Array_Entry()
Dim NewEntry as string = textbox1.text
EqArray.items.add(NewEntry)
msgbox(NewEntry & " has been added.")
End Sub

End Class
```